# Groovy remove beginning of path

Tags: java, groovy, replace, escaping

I'm trying to delete the beginning of a path that has '\' and ' ' in it.  I seem to be getting the some issues saying escape character issue at character 3.
Example:
   SomePath: C:\Users\ADMINISTRATOR\App Play\blah\blah

```
SomePath.replaceFirst('C:\\Users\\ADMINISTRATOR\\App Play\\', '');
```

Path should be blah\blah

I've tried:

```
SomePath.replaceFirst("C:\Users\ADMINISTRATOR\App Play\", "");
SomePath.replaceFirst("C:\\Users\\ADMINISTRATOR\\App Play\\", "");
SomePath.replaceFirst("C:\\\\Users\\\\ADMINISTRATOR\\\\App Play\\\\", "");

SomePath.replaceAll("C:\Users\ADMINISTRATOR\App Play\", "");
SomePath.replaceAll("C:\\Users\\ADMINISTRATOR\\App Play\\", "");
SomePath.replaceAll("C:\\\\Users\\\\ADMINISTRATOR\\\\App Play\\\\", "");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just gave it a try... the examples with four backslashes work for me:

```
def somePath = "C:\\Users\\ADMINISTRATOR\\App Play\\blah\\blah"
println somePath
somePath.replaceFirst("C:\\\\Users\\\\ADMINISTRATOR\\\\App Play\\\\", "");
```

The problem is that the string needs one escaping `\` and since the `replaceFirst` uses a regexp, the regexp-engine needs another `\` to escape the `\`. The result are four backslashes.

Btw: you can use string operations to get your path, but you could also try file operations like this:

```
def root= new File("C:\\Users\\ADMINISTRATOR\\App Play\\")
def full= new File("C:\\Users\\ADMINISTRATOR\\App Play\\blah\\blah")
def relPath = root.toPath().relativize( full.toPath() ).toFile()
println relPath
```

(taken from https://gist.github.com/ysb33r/5804364)

Answer (score 1):

You can tackle this problem differently. You could tokenize your input path using `\` as a delimiter and then you could pick the last 2 elements (`blah` and `blah`) or skip first 4 elements (`C:`, `Users`, `ADMINISTRATOR`, `App Play`). It depends which assumption is easier to deduct for you. Consider following example:

```groovy
def somePath = 'C:\\Users\\ADMINISTRATOR\\App Play\\blah\\blah'

// Build a new path by accepting the last 2 parts of the initial path
assert 'blah\\blah' == somePath.tokenize('\\')[-2..-1].join('\\')

// Build a new path by skipping the first 4 parts from initial path
assert 'blah\\blah' == somePath.tokenize('\\').drop(4).join('\\')
```

First option works better if you want **only** two last parts from the initial path. Second option works better if you can expect final path like `blah\blah\blahhhh` because you don't know how many nested children initial path contains and you want to start building a new path right after `\App Play\` .

Comment: What if you don't know how many path parts (directories) there are?